# Override HTML Template from custom module not working

Tags: magento2, template, html, overriding

I am trying to override HTML template in my custom module. I am working on Magento ver **2.2.2**

> Vendor/Moule/view/frontend, I have created a requirejs-config.js file:

```
    var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html': 'Vendor_Module/template/minicart/content.html',
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html': 'Vendor_Module/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
    }
};
```

**Copied custom file** `minicart\content.html` to

> Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\content.html and

**copied** `minicart/item/default.html` to

> Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html

Run below commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

After doing this, my default files disappear and my files are not showing, please let me know if I am doing something wrong.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check with private window or clear browser cache to see changes of __HTML and JS__ files

Comment: Yes, I have cleared browser cache but unable to see any changes.

Comment: Is I am doing something wrong or you can suggest any other method to override HTML template from a custom module?

Comment: Open Inspect element and go to network tab and find/open __content.html__ and check your changes

Comment: Yr Welcome -- :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple method to show changes of HTML and JS files without clearing the cache of the browser.

Right click on page and inspect element and open network tab. Now Double click on Html or Js file which you edited. And just full refresh html or js page in new tab.

Now Done. You can see changes on next refresh page.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Try following code:**

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content': '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/template/minicart/content',
        'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default': '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/template/minicart/item/default'
    }
};
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html
> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html