# How to load shipping methods on country and postcode change?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, drop-downs, country-regions, mixins, custom-shipping-method

I have written a custom shipping module, then I want to change custom shipping methods when country and post code changes. I heard there is a method call js mixin. any one have idea about it, need help to do it, thanks

Comment: can you pls provide any working screenshot or link i badly needed this..

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159518)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159518)

Answer (score 9):

You have to add mixin for `shipping-rates-validation-rules`

**Add mixins in `requirejs-config.js`**

> app/code/Vendor/ShippingModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules': {
                'Vendor_ShippingModule/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Now create `shipping-rates-validation-rules-mixin.js`**

> app/code/Vendor/ShippingModule/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules-mixin.js

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (targetFunction) {
        targetFunction.getObservableFields = function () {
            var self = this,
                observableFields = [];

            $.each(self.getRules(), function (carrier, fields) {
                $.each(fields, function (field) {
                    if (observableFields.indexOf(field) === -1) {
                        observableFields.push(field);
                    }
                });
            });

            observableFields.push('country_id'); // Load shipping method on Country chnage
            observableFields.push('postcode'); // Load shipping method on Postcode chnage
            //observableFields.push('telephone'); // Load shipping method on Phone Number chnage
            //observableFields.push('city'); // Load shipping method on City chnage


            return observableFields;
        }

        return targetFunction;
    };
});
```

Now run this commands:

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

If js or html changes not display refer this answer:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208844/35758

Comment: I have add you code, but nothing happened :(

Comment: can you describe how this code works. self.getRules() returns empty.

Comment: Working on M2.2.5

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot

Comment: Great. Worked without any single problem.

Comment: How can we load on `custom_attributes['custom_value']`

Comment: Actually I've just tested it with custom_atribute and it works only passing `custom_value`