# Shipping methods does not display on checkout page until I change country

Tags: magento2

I'm facing a strange issue with **Magento 2.2**
I've 4 allowed countries on my store
Shipping methods on checkout page are not displaying until user changes any country.
Default country is set to **United Arab Emirates**, if any user from **UAE** tries to place an order he sees **UAE** as default selection .. so he does not change it which causes no Shipping Methods.

I'm thinking either I should not select **UAE** as default country, but how to do it?

or

How to refresh shipping methods block automatically?

You can visit the store yourself at: [www.trydealz.com](https://trydealz.com)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if you add pincode shipping method get loaded as per Magento standard function. It is already working on your store.

But you need to load shipping method on city change or make zipcode mandatory

Update shipping on city field use below code

You need to add mixin for **shipping-rates-validation-rules**

Add mixins in your custom module **requirejs-config.js**

create file in custom module at `app/code/Vendorname/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` add below code to it

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules': {
                'Vendorname_ModuleName/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Create **shipping-rates-validation-rules-mixin.js** at `app/code/Vendorname/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules-mixin.js`

add below code to it

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (targetFunction) {
        targetFunction.getObservableFields = function () {
            var self = this,
                observableFields = [];

            $.each(self.getRules(), function (carrier, fields) {
                $.each(fields, function (field) {
                    if (observableFields.indexOf(field) === -1) {
                        observableFields.push(field);
                    }
                });
            });

          observableFields.push('city');


            return observableFields;
        }

        return targetFunction;
    };
});
```

For more reference check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212678/how-to-load-shipping-methods-on-country-and-postcode-change)

Comment: thanks for your response .. I've tried above solution .. but it is not working ... also added registration.php and etc/module.xml but no success